# Is there is any 12 word wallet recovery passphrase in bitcoin core

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind

How can i get wallet recovery passphrase of `wallet.dat` file. So that even if the wallet got corrupted or lost i can recover entire wallet using recovery passphrase.

Also i can't find any recovery passpharse command in API call list (https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_calls_list).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is not. Bitcoin Core does not use BIP39.

Comment: Is there is any other way i can recover wallet if wallet got corrupted

Comment: @AjitSoman You can go for regular "cloud" backups, encrypting them with a 12 word passphrase. That way you can always restore your wallet.dat to the last backed-up version and it's as secure as the encryption method you use and the passphrase.